# Can I change chapter font at the end of the book?

Tags: chapters

In this example :

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter{Chapter two}

\chapter{Chapter three}
New font and distance from the text here

\end{document}
```

I would like to set a different style for my last chapter title, ie different font and distance from the text. Is it possible to do a `\renew` command ?

Comment: you can use all the stuff from titlesec right before that last chapter

Comment: Yes, this is possible, for example, by redefinition of `\@makechapterhead`.

Comment: I already have the code for that, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `titlesec` for making the changes easier.

```
\documentclass[
  openany,% for the picture
  oneside,% for the picture
]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe} % for the picture

\newfontfamily{\cambria}{Cambria}
\newfontfamily{\antiqua}{Futura}[ % use Book Antiqua, I don't have it
  NFSSFamily=antiqua,
]

\newcommand{\specialchapters}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\cambria\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
    {20pt}
    {\Huge}%
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{10pt}%
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{antiqua}%
  \normalfont
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}
Distance from the text

\specialchapters

\chapter{Chapter two}
New font and distance from the text here

\end{document}
```

I used the options to `\documentclass` just for showing the two chapters side by side, with also the help of `shoframe`. Instead of Book Antiqua, that I don't own, I use a distinctive font just for showing that the setting is honored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Christian Hupfer's suggestion and based on previous answer I got to this solution :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter{Chapter two}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \vspace*{50\p@}
  {%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \setmainfont{Cambria}  % <- change 'Chapter 3' font here
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \large \normalfont \@chapapp \space \thechapter \par
        \nobreak \vskip 2\p@
        \setmainfont{Book Antiqua} % <- change title font here
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty \@M \fontsize{34}{38}\selectfont \normalfont #1\par
    \nobreak \vskip 40\p@ % <- change vertical distance from text here
  }}
\makeatother

\chapter{Chapter three}
New font and distance from the text

\end{document}
```